# How can i rename names of the files in a folder?

Tags: python, file, rename

I need to rename the whole images I have in a folder

`img1.jpg`  to be `1.jpg`

i tried like that

```
import os

s = open('images', 'w')
DIRECTORY = '/img/11/'

for img_filename in os.listdir(DIRECTORY):
    x = os.path.splitext(img_filename)[0].split('jpeg')
    x = img_filename.replace('img_', '')
    s.write(str(x) + '\n')
```

but need the changes on the files itself

Comment: `s.write(str(x)+'\n')` tells Python to write `str(x)+'\n'` to the file.  You want [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path

folder="C:\\Myfile\\path"

for img_filename in os.listdir(folder):
    os.rename(folder/img_filename, folder/ img_filename.replace('COCO_val2014_', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

you just had to use the os.rename() function

```
for img_filename in os.listdir(DIRECTORY):
    print(img_filename)
    x = img_filename.replace('COCO_val2014_','')
    print(x)
    os.rename(DIRECTORY+"\\"+img_filename,DIRECTORY+"\\"+x)
```